# How to read a CSV to pandas and get the value of one cell

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file and I want to:
1. Import the CSV as a Dataframe 
2. Read in a row at a time
3. Copy the VALUES of each cell to a separate string
4. Print the strings
5. Go to the next row and repeat steps 3-4 until done.

My code kind of works, it does read in and prints the first 2 rows, but there are 6 in my CSVC file.

I tried adding an index field but that didn't help much, 3 lines printed instead of 6.

Here is what my CSV file looks like: (the extra line return is so you can read it, not shown in my file.

00C525B70C246049E4.dwg,011021a.dwg

00CD5B2301DF204DCC.dwg,010636e.dwg

00F70B6C0B1EF04B54.dwg,005159v.dwg

0A02B9F7087BF040D5.dwg,003552n.dwg

0A1EE7CC078B404C64.dwg,020526c.dwg

0A1F67D201CCD04F81.doc,X1771-a.doc

```
import pandas

colnames = ['infocard','file_name']
data = pandas.read_csv('E:/test_Files_To_Rename.csv', names=colnames)

for i, elem in enumerate(data,0):

        sfile = data.loc[i,"infocard"]
        dst = data.loc[i,"file_name"]
     print( sfile +' to ' + dst )
```

Once I get the program to print the two different file names I want to replace the print statement with:

os.rename(sfile, dst)

so I can rename the files. I am testing with 6 files, my database has 50,000 files which is why I want to use a script.

This is what is displayed:

00C525B70C246049E4.dwg to 011021a.dwg

00CD5B2301DF204DCC.dwg to 010636e.dwg

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the dataframe after doing the file renames? If not, I would recommend using the `csv` module instead, as [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) may give you performance improvements and avoid reading from a separate data structure

Comment: Regarding your actual problem: When you call `enumerate` on a dataframe, you are only creating an enumeration of the column names in your df. Try printing out `list(enumerate(data))` to see what I mean. You might find `data.iterrows()` to be more helpful for your purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the following code to iterate through the .csv spreadsheet:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/home/stephen/Desktop/data.csv')

for i in range(len(df)):
    sfile = df.values[i][0]
    dst = df.values[i][1]
    print(sfile + ' to ' + dst)
```

I got the following output:

```
00C525B70C246049E4.dwg to 011021a.dwg
00CD5B2301DF204DCC.dwg to 010636e.dwg
00F70B6C0B1EF04B54.dwg to 005159v.dwg
0A02B9F7087BF040D5.dwg to 003552n.dwg
0A1EE7CC078B404C64.dwg to 020526c.dwg
0A1F67D201CCD04F81.doc to X1771-a.doc
```

This is the spreadsheet that I used:

[image: my spreadsheet]

Comment: That did it. I was able to add the line of code     os.rename(sfile, dst)     to rename the files. I had tried something like you said earlier BUT, I couldn't figure out how to get the column.